# Why doesn't this for loop work in GNU bash?

Tags: bash, macos

The bash code:

```
learn="Start learning from Javatpoint."
for learn in $learn
do
echo $learn
done  
echo "Thank You."
```

The result:

```
Start learning from Javatpoint.
Thank You.
```

The result should be like this:

```
Start
learning
from
Javatpoint.
Thank you.
```

Comment: Perhaps you are not running it in bash.  zsh will give you that output, but bash will do the word splitting.

Comment: `zsh` is the default login shell in recent MacOS releases.

Comment: Put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Yeah. even `dash` will do word splitting with that code

Comment: When you say `for learn in $learn`, what does `learn` even mean anymore (the original, or the word-splitted version)? It's hard to be sure when reading through quickly and will lead to bugs. Try using different variable names to make this easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I just ran your code on Gnu Bash 4.4.20 (Mint 19), it works fine, as you expect.